# How to convert This Format to JSON Format in perl?

Tags: json, perl, unix, format

i want to convert my original format to JSON format

My original format is :

```
RECORD
F recordType 18
F routingArea 04
F cellIdentifier 9E55
.
RECORD
F recordType 18
F routingArea 04
.
```

Convert like this:

```
[                              #openfile
 {                             #convert RECORD to [
   "recordType" : "18",        #cut prefix F and convert to json 
   "routingArea" : "04",
   "cellIdentifier" : "9E55"   #no comma before },
  },                       
  {
   "recordType" : "18",
   "routingArea" : "04"
  }                            #no comma before ]
]
```

How to develop scripts like this ?

Thanks,

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use JSON;

my @ar;
my $inner_hash = {};
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if ($_ eq '.') {
            push @ar, $inner_hash;
            $inner_hash = {}; 
    } elsif (/^F\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)$/) {
            $inner_hash->{$1} = $2; 
    }   
}

my $json = to_json(\@ar);
print $json, "\n";

__DATA__
RECORD
F recordType 18
F routingArea 04
F cellIdentifier 9E55
.
RECORD
F recordType 18
F routingArea 04
.
```